# How would you call backward porting testing?

Tags: regression-testing, terminology

A real life example- 
Linux Kernel **A** feature **B** was tested and released,

Linux Kernel **A+1** feature **B+1** was tested and released

Now feature **B+1** is ported back into Linux Kernel **A**

How should I call the testing of the this third stage ? Regression is the closest thing, but technically it refers to combinations that were tested before and are being retested now.

Comment: I think "backward porting testing", or the more succinct "backport testing", gets the point across.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't call it backward porting testing at all.  Within **A**, the feature from **B** is brand new, making it **A+2**.  It's a new feature in its own right.  The fact that **A**, **B**, **A+1** and **B+1** were tested and found stable doesn't guarantee that **A+(B+1)** will be bug free.  There isn't another name for that other than "testing".

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps "Backwards Compatibility Testing"?

Comment: Again- close, but not exact.
The ported feature will be an integral part of the older Kernel

Comment: Got it.  Perhaps just "Older Kernel Enhancement Testing" then.